# Including Asset Catalogue in Test Targets

Tags: xcode, xctest, asset-catalog

In one of my `XCTests` classes, I need to load up an image from an asset catalogue to test an image processing logic. However, it seems like using `UIImage(named: "imageName")` returns `nil` in the testing target.

I checked the testing target membership in my Asset Catalogue, is there anything else I should do to enable reading of the image from my `XCTest` classes?

Answer (score 16):

The answer by @mylovemhz is correct but incomplete. You need to reference the bundle:

Swift 3:

```
UIImage(named: "imageName", in: Bundle(for: MyTestClass.self), compatibleWith: nil)
```

Also ensure that your asset is included in the same target as your test class.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting similar functionality to work with `NSImage` (macOS).

Comment: Are you able to transfer this answer also to an objective-c one?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, you have to add them at runtime.

> If your tests use assets—data files, images, and so forth—they can be
>   added to the test bundle and accessed at run time using the NSBundle
>   APIs. Using `+[NSBundle bundleForClass:]` with your test class ensures
>   that you obtain the correct bundle to retrieve assets. For more
>   information, see [NSBundle Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsbundle).

In Swift, it would be something along the lines of:

```
let appBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: MyClass) as! AnyClass)
```